# asp.net MVC CheckboxList from viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Trying to figure out checkboxlists to implement in a few areas of our system. We have a table, tblJobs. This has a "AllocatedTo" property, which links to the UserID of "tblGlobalUsers". What we want is to be able to select multiple users, iterate through and insert a database record for each user selected to allocate the job to them.

I've tried following some other questions people asked on here, such as [Asp.Net MVC4 Display CheckboxList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650441/asp-net-mvc4-display-checkboxlist) and some other guides, but just getting nowhere with it unfortunately.

Will provide the code that anyone wants, or more information if needed.

Many thanks

**Edit:**

Have followed the link Stephen provided and attempted to update my viewmodel and controller as required. My viewmodel is now:

```
public class JobCreateViewModel
{
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int InventoryID { get; set; }
    public int ReportedBy { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public int JobType { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string NetworkLogin { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public virtual tblGlobalUser GlobalUserAllocated { get; set; }
    public virtual tblGlobalUser GlobalUserReportedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual tblInventory InventoryHardware { get; set; }
    public virtual tblJobType TypeJob { get; set; }
    public virtual tblJobPriority JobsPriority { get; set; }
}

public class JobsAllocateViewModel
{
    public JobsAllocateViewModel()
    {
        AllocatedTo = new List<JobCreateViewModel>();
    }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string NetworkLogin { get; set; }
    public List<JobCreateViewModel> AllocatedTo { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller is:

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(JobCreateViewModel viewModel)
    {
        JobsAllocateViewModel model = new JobsAllocateViewModel();

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            JobsContext.tblJobs.Add(new tblJob
            {
                JobTitle = viewModel.JobTitle,
                JobDescription = viewModel.Description,
                InventoryID = viewModel.InventoryHardware.InventoryID,
                ReportedBy = viewModel.GlobalUserReportedBy.UserID,
                AllocatedTo = model.AllocatedTo,
                Priority = viewModel.JobsPriority.PriorityID,
                JobType = viewModel.TypeJob.TypeID
            });          

            JobsContext.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Getting an error of "Cannot convert type systems.collections.generic.list to int" on `AllocatedTo = model.AllocatedTo,`

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for one option

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke taking a look now :)

Comment: `tblJob.AllocatedTo` is type of `int` but `viewModel.AllocatedTo` to typeof `List<JobCreateViewModel>` hence the error. Sorry, its unclear what your trying to do.

Comment: Well originally it was `AllocatedTo = viewModel.AllocatedTo`, but given that's where the checkbox is being made and after trying to get my around your answer for someone else, that's as far as I was able to get as it made sense given that whatever values are input from the checkboxlist would be going into that column.

Make sense?

Comment: _Make sense_? Not at all :)

Comment: What is definition of tblJob?

Comment: refer to this for an option -     http://stackoverflow.com/a/37221054/2924015